# Cannot resolve method executeQuery();

Tags: java, sqlite

I don't know why but when I try to use the the method "executeQuery()" inteliJ is throwing up it's hand and telling me 'Cannot resolve method executeQuery().

I've double checked that I've imported all packages to do with sql. I've looked at other articles of things that seem to be relevant. When I tried to 'shift'+'enter' it gave me options of editing settings that didn't seem to have any obvious solutions

```
package Student_Tech_Services_Tracking_Log;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TicketDB {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlite:products.db";

    protected ArrayList<Ticket> loadTickets(){

        final String srchSql = "select * from tickets";

        try(Connection conect = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            PreparedStatement prepState = conect.prepareStatement(srchSql)){

            ResultSet tikRs = srchSql.executeQuery();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

the expected results were that executeQuery() should not be highlighted as an error.

Comment: `srchSql` is a `String`. I think you meant `prepState.executeQuery()`

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet tikRs = srchSql.executeQuery();
```

Should be:

```
ResultSet tikRs = prepState.executeQuery();
```

executeQuery() is a method of Statements and not String.

You can read about it in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your code:
`executeQuery()` is not the method of `String` it is the method of `PrepareStatement` so do like that:

```
public class TicketDB {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:sqlite:products.db";

    protected ArrayList<Ticket> loadTickets(){

        final String srchSql = "select * from tickets";

        try(Connection conect = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            PreparedStatement prepState = conect.prepareStatement(srchSql)){

            ResultSet tikRs = prepState.executeQuery();

while(tikRs.next()){  
    System.out.println(tikRs.getInt(1)+" "+tikRs.getString(2));// here put your get logic..
    }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```